# ¿Como generar un evento en el MKPointAnnotation en IOS con Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Espero el siguiente ejemplo pueda explicarme mejor a mi pregunta.

```
//Tengo mi mapa declarado
@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

//Defino mi locacion
let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitud, longitud)

let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1)
//genero un region en zoom    
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

//declaramos una anotacion    
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = location  
annotation.title = "King David Kalakaua"
annotation.subtitle = "Waikiki Gateway Park"

//Agrego la región al mapa     
map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

//Agrego la anotación al mapa
map.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

La siguiente imagen muestra el ejemplo del código anterior

[image: imagen tomada de www.raywenderlich.com]

Mi duda es, si hay una forma de generar el evento de click a la ventana del mensaje del titulo y subtitulo, por ejemplo, que me lleve a otro ViewController y que dispare un mensaje. Realmente no se si sea posible, y apenas estoy comenzando en la programación en ios con swift y estoy algo perdido y en la documentación oficial no lo veo muy claro, gracias :)

Comment: Hola Jesús. Por favor brinda más información respecto. Muestra qué has intentado y qué te detiene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conseguir lo que buscas deberías asignarle la propiedad delegate a tu map:

`map.delegate = self`

Haz que tu controller conforme al protocolo `MKMapViewDelegate`, y a partir de ahí puedes implementar los métodos delegados, que harán que se reconozca el click en dicha vista:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }
    let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myAnnotation")

    annotationView.canShowCallout = true
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)

    return annotationView
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "openNextViewController", sender: self)
}
```